# Catlin multitype example

Tags: several-complex-variables

I asked this over question over stackexchange but did not get any answer.

This is a remark in a paper by Jiye Yu, "[Multitypes of Convex Domains](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24897057)", p. 838

> If (a smoothly bounded domain) $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$ is defined near $0$ by (the defining function) $r(z,w)=2 \Re w+2 \Re z^2+|z|^4$ then it is easy to see that ... (the Catlin multitype is) $\mathcal M(\partial \Omega,0)=(1,4).$

Can someone please explain how to obtain this, mainly what steps to follow in order to obtain this?